# Colocar várias classes no mesmo arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo, classes

No meu projeto eu tenho a classe `main` e criei novos arquivos de classe Java com o NetBeans para definir os objetos lá.

Só consigo usar na `main` uma das classes, as outras não consigo nem chamar os métodos.

É assim mesmo? Só posso usar no `main` um arquivo `.java` de classe? E se eu precisar de mais classes?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package iniciativa13ªera;

/**
 *
 * @author Giovane
 */
public class Iniciativa13ªEra {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Jogador giovane = new Jogador();
        giovane.setNomeJogador("Giovane - Ekth");
        giovane.setModDestreza(3);
        giovane.setModTamanho(0);

        giovane.calcular();
    }   

}
```

Esse é o meu main, e abaixo a primeira classe que eu fiz

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package iniciativa13ªera;

/**
 *
 * @author Giovane
 */
public class Jogador {
    //Atributos
    String nomeJogador;
    int modTamanho;
    int modDestreza;

    //------------- Métodos Personalizados

    //Muda o nome do Objeto (jogador)
    public void nome (String nome){
        this.setNomeJogador(nome);
    }

    //Muda o tamanho do Objeto (jogador)
    public void tamanho(int valor){
        this.setModTamanho(valor);
    }

    //Muda a destreza do Objeto (jogador)
    public void destreza(int valor){
        this.setModDestreza(valor);
    }

    //--------------- Métodos Especiais
    public String getNomeJogador() {
        return nomeJogador;
    }

    public void setNomeJogador(String nomeJogador) {
        this.nomeJogador = nomeJogador;
    }

    public int getModTamanho() {
        return modTamanho;
    }

    public void setModTamanho(int modTamanho) {
        this.modTamanho = modTamanho;
    }

    public int getModDestreza() {
        return modDestreza;
    }

    public void setModDestreza(int modDestreza) {
        this.modDestreza = modDestreza;
    }

    //---------------- Métodos Construtor
    public Jogador() {
        this.setModTamanho(0);
        this.setModDestreza(0);
    }
```

E por exemplo, se eu tentar puxar de uma segunda, que eu tenho lá feita, em outro `.java`, não funciona, como aquele `giovane.calcular()` que está definido numa terceira classe

Comment: Coloca seu código e mostra onde esta a ocorrer os erros?

Comment: Opa, só um segundo, vou organizar

Comment: @GiovaneMachado coloca o código na pergunta em seguida selecione ele e clique no botão `{}` **Amostra de código**, que serve para formatar.

Comment: @GiovaneMachado vc pode usar no `main` ou na classe que contem este método, todas as classes que estão dentro do pacote `iniciativa13ªera`. O nome do pacote é assim mesmo? Geralmente não se usa símbolos ou letras com acentos para dar nomes a pacotes. O seu poderia ficar assim `Iniciativa13`  ou `IniciativaTreze`, apenas com letras.

Comment: Sofri mas editei. É assim mesmo, posso mudar mas acho que nao resolve o problema

Comment: o erro aparece como
cannot find a symbol

Comment: Conferi, o pacote é o mesmo. Criei as classes clicando nele, nao tem como ser diferente

Comment: @GiovaneMachado tentou remover o simbolo `ª` do nome do pacote?

Comment: Removi, tambem notei lá que aparece agora "Erro ao fazer parsing do arquivo", referente a esse problema que estou tentando resolver. Mudar o nome do pacote não teve sucesso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java realmente limita ter mais de uma classe pública por arquivo. Todas as outras classes devem ser internas ao pacote. Mais ainda, a classe pública deve ter o mesmo nome do arquivo.

Se precisa de várias classes públicas, coloque uma em cada arquivo.

Outro ponto é que fica esquisito ter um pacote com mesmo nome da classe. Classes são objetos, pacotes são como sobrenomes desses objetos. Está conceitualmente errado.

Se o `calcular()` está definido em outra classe, deve usar em um objeto desta classe, não em um objeto que não tem este método.

Siga os comentários de não usar nomes com símbolos. Funciona, mas tem ferramentas, ruins, que tem problemas com isto.

Vejo outros problemas nesta classe, inclusive que gera erro em tempo de execução.

[Veja "funcionando" sem classes públicas](https://ideone.com/GsjmZ7). E [veja também com uma classe pública com o mesmo nome do arquivo](http://tpcg.io/7JIMpm) (este site sempre usa o nome `HelloWorld.java`). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/OnePerFile.java).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação!