# Erro de compilacao

Tags: java

Galera, ta dando dois erros e nao sei como resolvo.

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Pilha{

int elementos[];
int topo;

public Pilha(){
    elementos = new int[10000000];
    topo = -1;
}

public boolean empty(){
    return (topo == -1);
}

public int size (){
    return topo+1;
}

public int top(){
    return elementos[topo];
}

public int pop(){
    int e;
    e = elementos[topo];
    topo--;
    return e;
}

public void push(int e){
    topo++;
    elementos[topo] = e;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entrada = in.next();

    Pilha stack = new Pilha ();
    int var = entrada.length();

    int i = 0;

    while(i < var){
        if(!stack.empty() && stack.top() == '(' && entrada.charAt(i) == ')' ){
            stack.pop();
        }else stack.push(entrada.charAt(i));
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(entrada.size() - stack.size());
}
}
```

> ```
>  **2 errors
>  lista1.java:4: error: class Pilha is public, should be declared in a file named Pilha.java
>  public class Pilha{
>         ^
>  lista1.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
>          System.out.println(entrada.size() - stack.size());
>                                    ^
>    symbol:   method size()
>    location: variable entrada of type String**
> ```

LINK DO PROBLEMA: [aqui](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/26/B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lista1.java:4: error: class Pilha is public, should be declared in a file named Pilha.java

A classe Pilha é pública, e deve ser declarada em um arquivo chamado Pilha.java. <sup>[1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246632/colocar-v%C3%A1rias-classes-no-mesmo-arquivo)</sup>

> lista1.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
>           System.out.println(entrada.size() - stack.size());
>
> symbol:   method size()
>
> location: variable entrada of type String

A variável `entrada`, do tipo `String`, não possui o método `size()`. <sup>[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)</sup>

Portanto, para resolver esses problemas de compilação, você deve alterar o nome do arquivo conforme requisitado, e utilizar o [método length](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_length.htm) para o tamanho da `String`.